# Android Drawing Circle Chart

Tags: java, android, charts, drawable, paint

---

I need to create something like this.
Circle chart with with X zones with the same size but diffrent percentage value and color inside.
Any idea or advice how to write this?
Thx for help!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  That's a lot of work to ask us to do for you.  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that if you create new class that extends **View** and override the **onDraw** method and draw the pie chart on the canvas directly.
You can see something similar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/Piechart.htm). That example is not for Android specifically but for Java Mobile but it should be pretty much the same code to actually draw the arcs.

For more info about *custom views* on Android you should read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) first.